# How to find number of files in directory recursively along with its directory name linux

Tags: linux

I have following structure in directory on linux:

```
-dirA
    -dir1
        -dirX
        -dirY
    -dir2
        -dirX
        -dirY
    -dir2
        -dirX
        -dirY
    -dir2
        -dirX
        -dirY
    -dir2
        -dirX
        -dirY
    -dir2
        -dirX
        -dirY
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    -dirn
        -dirX
        -dirY
```

I want to get details for count of files as follows or any format:

```
dir1
dirX = count
dirY = count

dir2
dirX = count
dirY = count

dir3
dirX = count
dirY = count

......
......

dirn
dirX = count
dirY = count
```

note here folder name of dirX and dirY is same inside subdirectory dir1,dir2.....dirn

i used following command but it gives accumulated result:

```
find $DIR -exec stat -c '%F' {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

and this

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `while` loop should be enough

```
find "$DIR" -type d -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' path; do
        echo -e "$(ls -A -- "$path" | wc -l)\t$path"
    done
```

If you want them sorted by file count, you can append a `| sort -n` at the end of the command (right after the `done` keyword).

Comment: should this be saved as shell script and ran

Comment: @virendrao If you want, you can do that. Just replace `"$DIR"` by `"$1"` and save it as `myscript.sh` and run it as a script. e.g. `./myscript.sh "/path/to/directory"`. You can also run it directly: just replace `"$DIR"` with the path of the directory and paste it in a terminal.